# Spring Boot Admin unable to access pods

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot Admin application on Kubernetes using Spring Cloud Discovery (without Eureka or Zuul. It directly scrapes from Kubernetes API)

I've setup necessary RBAC and Ingress/Egress for the application to access Kubernetes API and the relevant services in the cluster.

The application is initially fetching all the information regarding the services but it's failing with below error when trying to communicate with individual pods in the namespace

`reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed`

When I try to curl the particular pods from the pod with Spring Boot Admin app:

1. When I try with FQDN of the service it returns fine with the response
   `curl {service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local/actuator/info`
2. When I do the same with the PodIp ( the one which Spring Boot Admin is struggling to connect to ):
   `curl 10.x.x.x:8080/actuator/info`
   I get this error
   `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Is there any particular netpol for pods to be accessed directly rather through the service's cluster IP? Because Spring Boot Admin tries to monitor all the individual pods in the services.

Or is there a workaround/approach where it isn't required by the Spring Boot Admin app to send requests to all the individual pods?